# TaLib hammer pattern not detected

Tags: python, candlestick-chart, ta-lib

I am working on an automated project for detecting trends. It will be an ensemble model using several different inputs and one of the inputs are detected candlestick patterns (the known patterns will be used 
 as inputs first and eventually just for a sanity check of an embedding layer that should recognize such patterns automatically).
While looking around i found a library that is supposed to be able to detect Candlestick Patterns like the hammer pattern. When i was testing it out i found some results which dont look correct to my eye.

```
import re
import numpy as np
import talib
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
data = np.load('usd-bitcoin.npy')
open_ = data[1, -10:].astype(float)
high_ = data[2, -10:].astype(float)
low_ = data[3, -10:].astype(float)
close_ = data[4, -10:].astype(float)

pio.renderers.default = "png"
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=data[0, -10:],
                                     open=open_,
                                     high=high_,
                                     low=low_,
                                     close=close_)])
fig.write_image("plots/fig1.png")

cdls = re.findall('(CDL\w*)', ' '.join(dir(talib)))
for cdl in cdls:
    toExec = getattr(talib, cdl)
    out    = toExec(open_, high_, low_, close_)
    print(str(out) + ' ' + cdl)
```

As you can see in the images below, the data and the candlestick plot seems to show 2 hammer patterns one 3 positions from the start and one 3 positions from the end. However the output of the program shows no hammers detected, is this working as its supposed to or am i supposed to preprocess the data somehow?

> [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] CDLHAMMER

[image: Data]
[image: CandleStick Plot]

Answer (score 2):

[from CDL Hammer Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tn8b.png)

https://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ta-lib/c/src/ta_func/ta_CDLHAMMER.c#l236

so what are you testing for should be the inverted hammer not the hammer.

/* Proceed with the calculation for the requested range.

```
* Must have:
* - small real body
* - long upper shadow
* - no, or very short, lower shadow
* - gap down
* The meaning of "short", "very short" and "long" is specified with TA_SetCandleSettings;
* outInteger is positive (1 to 100): inverted hammer is always bullish;
* the user should consider that an inverted hammer must appear in a downtrend, while this function does not consider it
```

https://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ta-lib/c/src/ta_func/ta_CDLINVERTEDHAMMER.c